# Rails-Thin server stopped on Production(live) mode.Website down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, production-environment, thin

I have put my ruby on rails project on production mode.I was running thin on production mode.Now suddenly the thin server seems to stop and give the following error while trying to start:-

```
/home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:158:in `delete': Read-only file system - tmp/pids/thin.3000.pid (Errno::EROFS)

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:158:in `remove_pid_file'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:175:in `remove_stale_pid_file'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:43:in `daemonize'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:62:in `start'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:199:in `run_command'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:155:in `run!'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/bin/thin:23:in `load'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'

        from /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woa/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I tried to delete the pid by using `$ lsof -wni tcp:3000`..But am not getting any output for it.
Also went through filezilla and tried to delete the pids from temp but am getting the following error.`General failure (server should provide error description)`.

Now my website is down for an hour Please help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate error is that your program couldn't remove the old pid file. Each process running on your computer has a number associated with it; servers often save this number to a file, to stop two running simultaneously.

The error message you got, though - "Read-only file system" - is rarely a good sign. If your computer encounters hard drive problems, it may remount the file system as read-only to prevent further damage. The output of `dmesg` may give you an idea whether this is the case here. You can probably get your server back up and running by rebooting it, but you need to be on the lookout for an imminent hard drive failure.

Comment: @alex-p..Thanks for the solution..but how do I change the permission of the file to 777..any idea

Comment: If the file system is read-only, you **cannot** change the permissions. Permissions involve a filesystem write, so you have to fix that first.

Comment: @alex-p..So the only way to solve this is to restart the server.Also my nginx was giving the same issue..So should I go ahead an restart the server.It is on azure

Comment: Rebooting the server will be easiest. Nginx was giving you the same error because it's trying to write to the same filesystem.

Comment: @alex-p..Thanks a lot mate..My site is up and running..But would like a little bit of detail why this could have happened.Where should I check it